# Radius of Convergence ratio test

Tags: special-functions, power-series

using the ratio test for the following

sum from n = 0 to infinity of
$$
\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{(m!)^2} x^{2m +10}
$$

I need to find the radius of convergence. I managed to get up to $|x|^2$ $\lim$ as n approaches $∞$ of $\frac{-1(m!)}{m+1}$ but then what is the limit of that?

Comment: hmmm, think you have made an error. First of all, shouldn't the sum run over $m$? Secondly, I get $\frac{-1}{(m+1)^2}$. However, I think we should be using the absolute convergence, so this fraction should be positive.

Comment: Here is what I suggest. We Use the ratio test for the absolute convergence of this series. This leaves us with lim$_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{(m+1)^2}|x^2|$. Now this fraction goes to zero which just leaves us with the $x^2$ term, and we know that for this series to converge, this limit needs to be $0\leq$ and $<1$. So what can we say about $x$?

Comment: so therefore the radius of convergence is infinite?

Comment: Indeed, this function is always zero for any x, and so this series converges. Also, by definition, the radius of convergence is $R = 1/L$ where $L$ is the above limit. When $L=0$, we define $R=\infty$

Comment: Actually, I didn't screw-up, but this is just the long hand way to do it. Using the radius of convergence test, all we had to do was check the limit of $1/(m+1)^2$

Answer (score 1):

The series is dominated (in absolute values) by
$$
x^{10}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(x^2)^m}{m!}=x^{10}e^{x^2}
$$
so absolute convergence is ensured for all $x\in\Bbb R$.